# Django ImageField - render only the <input> element

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-uploads

I have a Django form which has an `ImageField` in it, and I render the field like this in my template:

```
{{ form.my_image_field }}
```

The resulting HTML looks like this:

```html
Currently: <a href="https://....s3.amazonaws.com/....jpg">....jpg</a>
<input name="my_image_field-clear" id="my_image_field-clear_id" type="checkbox">
<label for="my_image_field-clear_id">Clear</label><br>
Change:
<input name="my_image_field" id="id_my_image_field" type="file">
```

I want to render only the `<input` element, since I am using the bootstra-fileinput library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-fileinput :

```html
<input name="my_image_field" id="id_my_image_field" type="file">
```

Is it possible to do this without writing the `<input>` tag manually in the template?

Comment: why don't you add just `<input name="my_image_field" id="id_my_image_field" type="file">` in template? not using django form

Comment: @seuling It's not flexible. Why write more code? For example what if tomorrow I need to change the name of the field? Or standardize all my widgets?

Comment: Few ways to go about this. Do you want this behavior only for `ImageField`s or for any/all input fields? Do you need the HTML elements actually gone, or would it be acceptable if the extra HTML elements were just visually/textually hidden?

Comment: @BabkenVardanyan you're right. But if you use `{{ form.my_image_field }}`, didn't you get only `input` field?

Comment: @sytech I want this behaviour only for `ImageFields`. It is acceptable if elements are just hidden, but that should include the `Currently:` and `Change:` texts as well.

Comment: @seuling No, please see the first part of the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally, `ImageField`s use the [`ClearableFileInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#clearablefileinput) widget. This widget by default uses the template name [`django/forms/widgets/clearable_file_input.html`.](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/clearable_file_input.html)

You can make your own `ClearableFileInput` widget subclass that uses a different template.

```
from django.forms.widgets import ClearableFileInput

class MyImageWidget(ClearableFileInput):
    template_name = "myapp/my_template.html"
```

The content of that template may just be simply the `<input>` part of the default template with the extraneous label and checkbox removed. You can customize it however you need. That might look like

```
<!-- myapp/my_template.html -->
<input type="{{ widget.type }}" name="{{ widget.name }}"{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>
```

Then in your form specify the widget for the ImageField

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    #  ...
    my_image_field = forms.ImageField(widget=MyImageWidget)
    #  ...
```

Django also provides a [`FileInput`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.FileInput) widget which uses a [plain template](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/file.html). If that suits your needs simply do

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    #  ...
    my_image_field = forms.ImageField(widget=forms.widgets.FileInput)
```

Alternatively, you could simply override the default template by creating the `django/forms/widgets/clearable_file_input.html` file in your project's `template` directory. However, this would apply the change to the rendering of all fields using the `ClearableFileInput` widget, so it is not as flexible of an approach.

Comment: Good answer, and there is already such a widget in Django called `FileInput` which uses a template with plain `<input>` tag, adjust your answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `form.name` and `form.id_for_label` template variables to dynamically set the `name` and `id` attributes of the `input` field for the `ImageField` based on the form's name and id

Here is an example for your project:

```
<input type="file" name="{{my_image_field.name}}" id="{{my_image_field.id_for_label}}">
```

Hope it will be helpful for orthers!